# PDF ( v > 1.5 ) to Image on LINUX

Tags: php, linux, image, pdf

FIRST OF ALL: I know there are a lot of related topics out there, but none seem to tell me anything new, none seem to work with pdf 1.6, or cost less then 500$ :) )

So, I have many pdf-s on a Linux Machine, they are all > 20 MB large, and all PHP v1.6; I need to convert the first page into a thumbnail

I tried:
1) PHP Libraries out there. None of them work with PDF > 1.5, or cost very much
2) GS + Imagick. Tried the latest version, works only sometimes and takes about 8 minutes per pdf.
3) PDF::EXTRACT or other CPAN PERL modules. Same problem with PDF > 1.5

I preferr a php solution ( although I really doubt there is one ), but a command line solution, java solution, perl solution, c++ solution, I'll set up a cron to do the processing.

Best Regards,
Gabriel

Comment: 8 minutes per PDF sounds odd. How large are the files?

Comment: when you say you've tried "GS+Imagick", does that mean you've used the Imagick extension for PHP? Or what does it mean?

Comment: @unicron: 30-50 MB large. Full of images and everything. They are magazines.

Comment: @gnud: yes, that's what it means

Comment: have you tried Zend_Pdf? I see that there is Zend_Pdf_Page::saveGS() http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.7/Zend_Pdf/Zend_Pdf_Page.html#saveGS

Comment: PDF versions are largely irrelevant.  Is there some particular feature in these PDFs that was added in 1.6 that you need?  PDF renders are pretty backward-compatible beasts.  Features in 1.6 that you might care about... 3D in PDF, DeviceN colorspace enhancements,  OCG enhancements (locks & expressions), **embedding OpentType/CFF** fonts.  I'm going to guess you're either listening to someone in marketing or need embedded OTF/CFF fonts.  How about it?

Comment: Look, Gabriel -- you didn't tell us **how exactly** you proceeded with your command when you used "GS+Imagick". I **bet** that I can create a thumbnail from the first page of any of your PDFs in 8 seconds rather than in 8 minutes, just using Ghostscript.... But first tell the command you used, so we can spot where your problem comes from. Oh, and can you provide a (link to a) sample PDF?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `evince-thumbnailer`.
It's use is as simple as `evince-thumbnailer input.pdf output.png`. You can easily call it from PHP and gather it's output.

Comment: don,t have exec rights from PHP :) But still, it's a start point. I'll check if it works with PDF 1.6. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Ghostscript via the command line, you can interpret any PDF or PS-file, and send it to a "device". A device might be an actual printer, or it might create another file.

Here's an example command to convert the first page of the PDF file "magazine.pdf" to a JPEG image named "cover.jpg", in 250ppi resolution.

```
$gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=cover.jpg -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE \
-q -r250 -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 magazine.pdf
```